# GIT permissions : Repository inside a repository

Tags: linux, git, security, repository, repository-design

i have folder structure as below :

```
repo1
|
|---file1
|---fold1
    |
    |---file2
|---repo2
    |
    |
    |---file3
```

Lets say i have two users, `user1` and `user2`.

Now i need to :

1. setup `repo1` and `repo2` as two separate `GIT repositories`.
2. setup `user1` to have permission for `repo1` and `user2` for `repo2`.
3. `user1` should be able to pull `file1` and `fold1` contents but not `repo2`
4. `user2` should be able to pull `repo2` and files under it but not `repo1`
5. after `user2` makes changes and commits to `repo2`, it should be reflected under `repo1` in the server

Is this level of permissions possible with `GIT`?

Comment: This seems very unusual - what are you trying to do?

Comment: @1615903 i have existing project with above folder structure, we are setting up GIT repository for that project , so i want certain users to access only a subfolder inside main folder while some users should have access to only the main fodler.

Comment: that much I understood from the question, but I'm wondering why. Why can't user1 have access to repo2's content? Submodules would be a suitable option if you can give user1 at least a read access to repo2.

Comment: @1615903 user1 should not have access to repo2 because files inside that are app specific only that app owner should be able to see and edit them.user2 is app specific and he should not be able to see ops contents.

Answer (score 2):

see 'git submodule'.

- passwords and permissions on the server repo's can be set in the server
- each user would have to have their own local repositories.
- repo1 would be main module,  repo2 would be the sub module.  see.

  git help submodule
- if user2 pushed (from local to server, after committing) to repo2, user1 would pull the changes with a 'git submodule update' command, but not automatially.

Comment: thanks @gregg i read that `git subtree` better than `git submodule` so i followed this post [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository/17864475#17864475 ]  but after i separate out a subdirectory as a repository , im not sure how to merge it back and view in the parent directory.